# How can i change background of programmatically added button in C# Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I tried to make this, that way: btn.Background(Android.Graphics.Color holo_blue_dark); but it doesn't work, here is my code of adding this button (it's working fine except this background). Can you tell how to set other properties like height, margin etc.?

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
i++;
title = title.Trim(new Char[] { '"', '<', '>' });
btn.Text = title;
btn.Id = i;
layout.AddView(btn);
```

Comment: Use 
`btn.SetBackgroundColor (Color.Argb (0, 0, 0, 0));`
The parameters are for alpha, red, green and blue

Comment: thank you that also works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried SetBackgroundColor()?

```
btn.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow);
```